# How to resolve $a+b+c = 0$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2 = d$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have an equation for which I am seeking a generic solution.

I have three numbers where the following constraints exist:

$a+b+c=0$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2=d$ where $d$ is fixed and some small amount of error is permissible.

An example of this is where I start with

$$ a = -0.200498879495, b = -0.0565542688671, c = 0.257053148362, d = 0.125$$

With these values $a, b$ and $c$ fulfill the first requirement but not the second. To do this (in this example) I need to end up with the following:

$$ a' = -0.204124145232000, b' = -0.0747146046384, c' = 0.27883874987 $$

which fulfills my requirements.

Note that I have had to add $0.021785601508$ to $c$ and subtract $0.003625265737$ from $a$ and $0.0181603357713$ from b, where $0.021785601508-0.00362526573-0.0181603357713 \approx 0$

Background information is that I am working with weights at the vertices of an equilateral triangle. I need to normalise these weights so that they conform to the requirements of the above equations. This first is easy, but I haven't seen my way clear to solving the second yet. As such any help is gratefully received.

[edit]

I should probaby add a mention that the radius of circumscribed circle of the triangle that I am working with is $0.288675134595$, worked backwards from the edge length of $0.5$

[edit 2]

Another indicator of good values is that $cos(a'/0.288675134595), cos(b'/0.288675134595), cos(c'/0.288675134595)$ all indicate 120 degree separation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to take some given numbers $(a,b,c)$ and adjust them so that they satisfy the two given constraints. In doing this, it might be useful to make the adjustments as small as possible.

As @Peter Franek pointed out, the points where $a+b+c=0$ lie on the plane through the origin with unit normal $\mathbf{N} = (1,1,1)/\sqrt3$, and the points where $a^2+b^2+c^2 = d$ lie on a sphere of radius $\sqrt{d}$ centered at the origin. The intersection of the plane and the sphere is a circle of radius $\sqrt{d}$, again centered at the origin. We want to "nudge" our given point $\mathbf{P} = (a,b,c)$ onto this circle.

We do it in two steps:

(1) First, project $\mathbf{P}$ onto the plane to get a point $\mathbf{Q}$. The formula for $\mathbf{Q}$:
$$
\mathbf{Q} = \mathbf{P} - (\mathbf{P} \cdot \mathbf{N}) \mathbf{N}
$$
(2) Next, scale the length of $\mathbf{Q}$ to make it lie on the circle. In other words, compute:
$$
\mathbf{R} = \frac{\sqrt{d}\mathbf{Q}}{\|\mathbf{Q}\|}
$$
The point $\mathbf{R}$ has the required properties, and it's as close as possible to the original point $\mathbf{P}$

Here is some pseudocode, which might be easier for you to understand than the mathematical formulae:

```
k = 1.0/sqrt(3)         // So that N = (k,k,k)
PN = a*k + b*k + c*k    // The dot product of P and N
qx = a - PN*k
qy = b - PN*k
qz = c - PN*k
normQ = sqrt(qx*qx + qy*qy + qz*qz)  // The norm (length) of vector Q
scale = sqrt(d)/normQ
anew = rx = scale*qx
bnew = ry = scale*qy
cnew = rz = scale*qz
```

Comment: Having just a little trouble following the process here.  Also a little confused about the circle size when the original triangle had a larger circle as now mentioned in the edits above.  One problem here is, of course, that I'm a programmer and not a mathematician so it often takes a while for the penny to drop, as it were.

Comment: Thanks for the psuedo code. Makes it a lot easier for me :-)

Comment: The circle we're talking about here is merely a conceptual one, used to motivate the formulae. It bears no relationship to your original circle (as far as I know). The formulae and code above should work regardless of the size of your original circle and triangle.

Comment: Just working through the pseudocode. My start condition is that $a+b+c ≈ 0$ and $PN=a*k+b*k+c*k$ also gives very close to zero. Am I missing something?

Comment: If $a+b+c$ is close to zero. then certainly $PN$ will also be close to zero, because actually $PN = k*(a+b+c)$. Geometrically, this means that the point $P$ is already close to the plane, so $Q$ will be almost the same as $P$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for that it works a treat.  Thanks especially for the pseudocode, it made the answer a lot easier to understand and to implement.

Comment: Just out of interest, is there a 3-space equivalent to this algorithm?

Answer (score 9):

Geometrically, the solution set is just an intersection of a sphere of radius $\sqrt{d}$ with a plane $x+y+z=0$. As there is an orthonormal basis of $x+y+z=0$ that consists of $e_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,-1,0)$ and $e_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}(1,1,-2)$, you can generate solutions just by the formula $$\sqrt{d}\cos\alpha \,e_1+\sqrt{d}\sin\alpha \,e_2.$$

Comment: Many thanks for the response. Would you be able to expand a little for me. My maths knowledge is somewhat limited and I'm not sure that I follow the constructs for e1 and e2.

Comment: @KevinAcres Do you know how to add vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$? Do you know that $\cos^2\alpha+\sin^2\alpha=1$ for any $\alpha$? If yes, you can verify that $(a,b,c)=\sqrt{d}(\cos \alpha) e_1 + \sqrt{d}(\sin\alpha) e_2$ satisfy your equations by a direct computation (for any $\alpha$). (My choice of $e_1$ and $e_2$ is so that they have unit length and are orthogonal to each other and the sum of their coordinates is zero)

Comment: Sorry, but I'm way outside of my comfort zone here.  It's just that I'm working on a project were excursions into this kind of math is somewhat necessary. So, in answer to your question, I don't know how to add vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ but I'll need to learn pretty quickly.

Comment: If you are not familiar with vectors and scalar product, you can still verify by a direct computation that $a=\sqrt{d}(\cos\alpha/\sqrt{2}+\sin\alpha/\sqrt{6})$, $b=\sqrt{d}(-\cos\alpha/\sqrt{2}+\sin\alpha/\sqrt{6})$, $c=\sqrt{d}(-2\sin\alpha/\sqrt{6})$ solves your equations for any $\alpha$. Moreover, every solution looks like this.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll code it up and check it out once I get home tonight.

Comment: I had a chance to try this and it certainly provides the right values.  Unfortunately, in my case, $\alpha$ is the unknown in the equation. I have to normalise $(a,b,c)$ first in order to get agreement on a reasonable value for $\alpha$.